# Devextreme scheduler bind function to dataSource?

Tags: javascript, devextreme

I have an function which does ajax call and gets data. The function is similliar to

```
function loadData(callback) {
    //do ajax
    if(callback) {
       callback(data.data);
    }
}
```

How can i bind this function to the scheduler dataSource?
Tried with this

```
options: {
   dataSource: loadData(function(data) {
        return data;
   });
}
```

and it does return the data i need when i do `console.log` in the function but if i want to add another options like `views` it **expects ; somewhere and it doesnt work**

How can i achieve that and render the scheduler with the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to bind a remote data to dxScheduler I suggest you use the [customStore](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/16_2/ApiReference/Data_Layer/CustomStore/) object.

```
var dataSource = new DevExpress.data.DataSource({
    load: function() {
        // make ajax request here and return promise
    }
});

$("#scheduler").dxScheduler({
    //...
    dataSource: dataSource 
});
```

The demo is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/c2qzq4b5/).

More information about DevExtreme data layer is [here](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/16_2/Guide/Data_Layer/Data_Layer/).